# Best way to setup python on a new Mac

Tags: python, macos, pip, anaconda, homebrew

I just bought a new Mac and would like to avoid messing up any python dependencies and paths like I did when using Homebrew and pip in parallel with my old Mac. What is the cleanest and most powerful way of setting up a python distribution and installing all necessary packages, like e.g. scipy, matplotlib, numpy, etc.:

- Homebrew
- pip (maybe via Homebrew?)
- virtual environments/anaconda

What do I need to be careful with?

Comment: [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question pretty much sums up how I have my set up. I based it off of doing a few online readings on clean set ups. To summarize:

1. It is recommended to install Python 2 and 3 via HomeBrew for your global set up
2. The above step should install pip AFAIK
3. Virtualenv is super useful for sandboxing different local environments.

Note that Anaconda would allow you to create envs also (see https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html), plus you get all those scientific packages you mentioned for "free" without too many other installs. To get a little meta, you can even use Brew to install anaconda: `brew cask install anaconda` :)

---

Things to keep in mind:

- Don't do too many installs on your global set up and try to keep it bare.
- Leverage the virtual envs and do all your installs and customize as needed. For example, you can have one for python 2 with your scientific packages and another for python 3 with barely anything just for debugging.

Here are a couple of references I looked at while I completed my set up:

https://github.com/nicolashery/mac-dev-setup#python

https://medium.com/@briantorresgil/definitive-guide-to-python-on-mac-osx-65acd8d969d0

---

Farewell tip: If you do somehow mess up your python 2 and python 3 set up, you can use `brew doctor` and `brew prune` to remove any broken sym links

best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the data science libs, Anaconda is by far the easiest way of doing it in my experience.

Do make use of virtual environments when possible. It'll help your machine remain tidy.

Comment: Yes Anaconda is nice and easy.  Its is much simpler to make virtual environments. Anaconda also distributes Spyder, a python IDE.